# if smiliar foreach then add together Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

i want to add the values if they were same and similar

like this :

```
AAA     122
AAA     111
AAA     225
AAA     222
AAA     115
AAA     12
AAA     2
AAA     123
AAA     222
BBB     12
```

here i want add all of 'AAA' values and just show one of them

this is my view:

```
@foreach($WhoSales as $WhoSales)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $WhoSales->user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $WhoSales->quantity }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

and my controller:

```
$WhoSales = SalesReport::where('department_id', Auth::user()->department_id)->get();
```

Comment: please explain more...

Comment: using `SUM` and  `GROUP BY` in your query resolves the issue. You don't need to loop through the result collection